# How we can write multiple select keyword in a single mysql query using Magento?

Tags: magento

here is my query and this give proper ouput.
But How can I set it according to magento rules?

```
SELECT main_table.*, 
   (select company from sales_flat_order_address sfoa where sfoa.entity_id=sfo.billing_address_id) as bill_to_company,
   (select company from sales_flat_order_address sfoa where sfoa.entity_id=sfo.shipping_address_id) as ship_to_company
          FROM sales_flat_order_grid as main_table inner join sales_flat_order as sfo 
                    on main_table.entity_id = sfo.entity_id
```

please help me....

Thanks & Reagards
Praful

Comment: google Magento raw sql query :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use magento default connection Model

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

$result=$write->query("your query as like mysql query no different");

$row = $readresult->fetch(); // this will fetch all your data
```